# DFS in DFS, DFS with a known string

Tags: algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I am looking for the complexity calculation of my code. It is simply a DFS(depth first search) in DFS. A DFS runs on a graph (state machine) from end to start (backward search). Whenever it reaches to start, it accumulates the string that made it reach to start and tries that string on another graph with another DFS to check if it also reaches to start state on the other graph with the same string.

The outer DFS complexity is definetely O(Vo+Eo) where Vo : number of vertex in outer graph and Eo : number of edges in outer graph. But what's the complexity of inside DFS when the string that will be followed is known?

And if possible, can you also answer for the whole complexity of the algorithm?

I am not sure whether it is O((Eo+Vo)+(Ei+Vi)) or O((Eo+Vo)(Ei+Vi)) or smtg .else

Thank you in advance,

Comment: O( |string| (Eo+Vo)) ..where |string| is size of string

Comment: thanks Khaled. it's what I thought at first but what about the paths in second DFS that searched and not ended in a start state? Shouldn't there be some cumulative term instead of just |string| ?

Comment: It's because you are using the graph to do a Finite State Machine parsing, if it's deterministic then it's O((Eo+Vo)+|string|), if it's stochastic then it's O((Eo+Vo)*|string|)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you do in case the second DFS fails. By failing I mean tells you that the second graph does not contain the string found in the first DFS.

If the second DFS failing means you backtrack and search for another string in the first DFS and then try the second DFS again, then your complexity is `O((Eo+Vo)*(Ei+Vi))` because you may in the worst case do a full DFS of the second graph for every single DFS path to the start node in the first DFS.

If the second DFS failing means you stop, then you will at worst perform a single DFS of the first graph and a single DFS of the second graph giving you a `O((Eo+Vo)+(Ei+Vi))` worst case complexity.

The fact that you are DFSing to check if the graph contains a string means that in some cases you may be able to terminate your DFS early (for example you reach a non-start vertex with no characters remaining to check). However, whether you will be able to terminate early depends entirely on the structure of the graph so I would say that the second DFS is in the worst case still `O(Ei+Vi)` because with a nasty graph you may still find yourself going through all the edges and all the vertices.

Comment: there is no possibilty of not reaching to the start in the second DFS. it has to reach to start via the string obtained in first DFS. So it tries each string -that reaches to start in first DFS- in the second DFS.

Since the worst case is our concern and worst case cannot be worse than |string| as Khaled said it shouldn't be something related with O(Ei+Vi).

The thing that I got stuck is what if it tries that string of length |string| many times and reaches to start finally. than it should also be greater that |string|

Comment: @ŞuleSelin What if in the second graph you have a vertex which has a number of edges labelled with the same character going out of it? Is that possible? I think with `O(Ei+Vi)` you are safe because the second DFS cannot be more than that and so you have a good (if perhaps not the smallest) upper bound.

Comment: now I got your point. It is definetely a safe bound but it's not the exact bound that I'm looking for, I guess. and for the question, no it's not possible that same character goes out for different edges, it is a DFA. But a vertex can have edges coming in from same character from other vertices and since this is a backward search, the case that includes entering into wrong paths and then finding the correct path may occur. Is your answer valid in such a case?

Comment: @ŞuleSelin If the second graph is a DFA why do you not start the second search from the start node and check if it enters into the end node? That should be equivalent to starting from the end node and checking if it reaches start, but faster. Then you would be sure you never enter wrong paths and so your runtime would be `O((Eo+Vo)*|string|))`.

Comment: yes it should be easier but I have more than one start, backtracking to any start seemed easier to me at the beginning. Also there are unobservable events that can make the string obtained from first DFS (fully observable string) to end in very different places unfortunately. Thank you for your suggestion but anyway any answer for the current case?

Comment: @ŞuleSelin If you can have multiple wrong paths then I would say you cannot use `|string|` as an upper bound. With each wrong path you get another `|string|` number of operations. At most you do `O(Ei+Vi)` operations so I would say that given what you have told me about the graph my original answer is a good bound on the runtime.